# Generator to Main changeover issue RCCB not moving up

Tags: power-supply, wiring, switching, circuit-breaker, bad-wiring

RCCB not moving to up position while DG to EB ( generator to mains) changeover.

I live in a community where we have almost 1200 apartments in India which will serve power through generators when the main supply goes OFF. (230v)

The following diagram shows my wiring in my distribution board.

My four-room apartment has 4 MCB for each room for lighting circuits and one MCB for heating circuits.

[image: wiring]

Whenever a change over happens from the generator to main, RCCB won't automatically move the knob from down position to up position, there is no issue while, main to the generator changeover, in this case, RCCB will automatically move the knob from up position to the down position.

So I have to manually go and move the knob in RCCB towards the above position, bring the power back from mains.

How to solve the problem, looks like the wiring problem. Let me know what more information required, I can post info and pictures based on requests to solve this.

I need to go and move RCCB switch to manually up in the middle of my sleep at night, so many sleepless nights, no expert electricians still can't solve it.

Comment: I suspect that it is not supposed to trip the RCCB when it switches to gen.

Comment: Just to update, tripping is happening NOT when Mains to DG changeover, it's happening when DG to Mains changeover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, first MCB in lighting line is the cause, means, when I turn off 1 st MCB in the lighting line, immediately after Mains changes to DG, then there is no tripping when DG changes to EB.

This means, the issue is happening in the 1st MCB circuit, there is some device, in this circuit I need to see , it's touching the ground, which caused the tripping of RCCB.